# Issue with visual basic excel

Tags: excel, vba

Im having an issue to input the name in the textBox, i tried multiple configurations w no success. You ll can see the line with textbox just below LAURELISSA. Well i want to enter the name I want.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Dim name As String
'name = TextBox1.Text

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("carnet")
    
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    lastRow = sht.UsedRange.Rows(sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    
    Dim lastCol As Integer
    lastCol = sht.UsedRange.Columns(sht.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column
    
    Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet
    
    With sht.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
        .AutoFilter
        
'TextBox1.Text = Range("B2:B99").Value
'For i = 2 To lastRow
'Me.TextBox1 = Sheets("carnet").Cells(i, "B").Value

        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="LAURICELLA"
        '.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="TextBox1"  
        
        
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).name = "Duplicate_Sheet_" & Sheets.Count
        Set pasteSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Duplicate_Sheet_" & Sheets.Count - 1)
        
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        pasteSheet.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
        
        UserForm1.Hide
                
        .AutoFilter
    End With
End Sub
```

Thanks you.

Comment: Is `"TextBox1"` in the autofilter supposed to be the same as `TextBox1.Text`? Or what exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

When you put quote "TextBox1" so it's searching for "TextBox1" word. You need to search what is your control. TexBox1 is your control, and if you want to get what's written you need Text parameter. Read the basics :)

```
Your line: .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="TextBox1" 

It should be: .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=TextBox1.Text
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't work like this I tried this :
Dim strname As String
....
.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="TextBox1.Text"

Comment: @AmineDjalil you don't need quotes if you want to get text from control. Copy paste like I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

`TextBox1.Text = Range("B2:B99").Value` Is not valid, since excel can't return a single value for multiple cells.

`For i = 2 To lastRow`
`Me.TextBox1 = Sheets("carnet").Cells(i, "B").Value` Is going in the right direction, but as you surely noticed, you will only get the last value, ergo the value from `"B99"` – assuming this is the last row.
To return the concatination of all the values held by the cells, you have to keep the previously read values:

```
For i = 2 To lastRow  
    Me.TextBox1 = Me.TextBox1 & Sheets("carnet").Cells(i, "B").Value
Next i
```

Or `Me.TextBox1 = Me.TextBox1 & " " & Sheets("carnet").Cells(i, "B").Value` if you need a delimiter.

We use the `&` to put the strings together, and start with what is already in the box to add on each cell. This will however give you the value of **ALL** the cells. If you wish to have a single value, you need a slightly different approach, depending on what exaclty you are looking for

Then, to filter on the content of the textbox, you need to again refer to the textbox, and  not a string – string being pretty much anything inside of "quotes"

```
.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Me.TextBox1
```

This is assuming that Me.TextBox1 points toward the correct textbox, which would be a textbox on the same form as the button. Otherwise it's *`<form name>.Textbox1`*